# Как в bootstrap 3 убрать затенение по краям carousel?

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass, scss

Использую стандартный код [отсюда](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).
Хочется убрать затенение. Поковырялся в стилях и увидел, что за это затенение отвечает параметр `background-image` в классе `carousel-control`, соответственно их два: `.left` и `.right`.
Попытался выставить в стилях этот параметр в `none` - попробовал такой вариант:

```
.carousel-control {
  .left {
    background-image: none;
  }

  .right {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Не сработало. Видимо, или SASS так не умеет, или я ошибся в синтаксисе.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать это затенение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написанный код в вопросе означает, что класс 'left' вложен в 'carousel-control'.
А в примере с сайта w3c оба класс присутствуют на элементе одновременно -
для этого используется амперсанд:

```
.carousel-control {
  &.left {
    background-image: none;
  }

  &.right {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: все сработало,большое спасибо.скажите,какие функции выполняет амперсанд в sass?я просто только начал в нем разбираться,еще непривычно и не всегда  понятно что к чему

Comment: `&` используется для объединения селекторов: чтобы создать каскадное правило для нескольких селекторов, их можно записать через амперсанд, как в моём ответе выше. то бишь, правило `.carousel-control {...
  &.left {...` равносильно селектору `.carousel-control.left`